# ReplaceAll with backslashes

Tags: java, regex

I want to convert all the occurences of `\&quot;` in a text file into empty string.
So basically I want to convert  to .

I used the following method but it doesnt seem to work:

```
sb.toString().replaceAll("\\&quot;", "");
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sb.toString().replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\&quot;"), "");
```

Comment: Have you tried your code or just copy-pasted it from Rahul? I am asking since there is no such a thing as `Regex.quote` in Java.

Comment: Sorry, I misread answers time, but still you should test answers before posting them.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks for mentioning the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of `replaceAll` which uses regex, use simple `replace` which will automatically escape all regex metacharacters (like in your case `"\\"`) in pattern you want to replace.

```
String replaced = sb.toString().replace("\\&quot;", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in a regular expression, the `\` character has a special meaning.  You need to escape it with a second `\`.  Then both `\` characters need to be escaped from the Java compiler.  You actually need to write

```
sb.toString().replaceAll("\\\\&quot;", "");
```